# Bash free command stops working

Tags: linux, bash, tail, free-command

I am trying to do following:

Get output of `free -mo` , take the 2nd line and log it to a file every 30 seconds.

When I run

```
$free -mo -s 30
```

It runs and displays output every 30 seconds.

But when I run

```
$ free -mo -s 30 | head -2 | tail -1
```

It runs only once. I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

free Manual says free -s 30 run the command every 30 seconds.

Comment: Use [`watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch).

Comment: DCoder: This should really be an answer!

Comment: @MatsPetersson: after re-reading the question, the OP wants to log the results to a file, `watch` is for interactive viewing and redirecting its output to a file pollutes it with control codes... probably more work than just building a manual while/sleep loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`head -2` returns only the first 2 lines of output then quits. `tail -1` returns the last line, then quits. When any program quits in a pipeline, it kills the entire pipeline, so `free` is stopped when `head` and `tail` finish.

Answer (score 0):

Use `free -mo -s 30 &> test.txt &`

This will take all of the output from the `free` command and output it to test.txt and run it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
free -mos 30 | grep 'Mem:' >yourlog.txt
```

(but you might be better considering something like sar to capture this kind of data - it can also reports lots of other things - just postpone the filtering/extraction until you generate a resport from the data).

Answer (score 0):

Will Hartung is right. Instead do this:

> while true; do free -mo | head -2 | tail -1; sleep 30; done

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers. I was trying to monitor memory utilization of a process. I think I got it.

```
START_TIME=$(date);
cd /data;

INPUT_DATA=$1;
CODE_FILE=$2;
TIMES=$3;

echo "$START_TIME" > "$CODE_FILE.freeMemory_$TIMES.log";
free -mo -s 30 >> "$CODE_FILE.freeMemory_$TIMES.log" &
freepid=$!;

sleep 1m;
#echo "PID generated for free command -- $freepid";
START_TIME=$(date);
i=0;
while [ $i -le $TIMES ]
    do
            sh runCode.sh $CODE_FILE "output.csv" $INPUT_DATA;
            i=`expr $i + 1`
    done

END_TIME=$(date);
echo "process started at $START_TIME and ended at $END_TIME " ;
sleep 1m;
kill -9 $freepid;
END_TIME=$(date);
echo "$END_TIME" >> "$CODE_FILE.freeMemory_$TIMES.log";
```